# Shortcode to list post titles from certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, list, wordpress-theming, shortcode

i found this great snippet of code on http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts and I edited it a little to suit me. It works.

```
<p>
    <?php


        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 1 );

        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </br>
     <?php endforeach; 
     wp_reset_postdata();?>
</p>
```

I would like to transform it into a shortcode with one changeable variable - category id. But, well, since I don't know php, all I came up is:

```
function tytuly_postow($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'id' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => $id );
   $q ="<p>
    <?php

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </br>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</p>";
}
add_shortcode('tytuly','lista_postow');
```

Of course, it doesn't work. I use Karma theme and added it in shortcodes.php file. Please, help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is certainly on the right track. Here's how I'd do it:

```
function tytuly_postow( $atts ) {
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'id' => 1,
   ), $atts ) );

   $posts = get_posts( array(
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'cat'       => $id,
   ) );

   $output = '';

   if ( $posts ) {
       $output .= '<p>';

       foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
           $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ) . '<br />';
       } 

       $output .= '</p>';
   }

   return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'tytuly', 'tytuly_postow' );
```

Offset by default is 0 so you don't need to add it as an argument. I've set posts_per_page to -1. This means get all.

Since you're just listing off titles it may make sense to order them by title. At the moment they'll be ordered by date descending.

I'm setting output to a blank string and returning output at the end. This means no matter what happens the shortcode will always return something, even if that something happens to be an empty string.

Then I'm checking if posts were found. If that's the case I'm adding a paragraph tag before and after the foreach. This was to match your original code.

Finally it loops through each post and uses the_title filter on the post titles then ends each title with a break tag.

Comment: Your add_shortcode function isn't going to work, since the function is called `tytuly_postow` and not `lista_postow`

Comment: My mistake. Copied and pasted from the OP. Since been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

By taking a look at the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and [add_shortcode Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode), you can check that the parameters of function `add_shortcode` are `$tag` and `$func`.
So, to start fixing your code, you need to fix it:

```
//[tutuly]
function tytuly_postow($atts) {
    ...
}
add_shortcode('tytuly', 'tytuly_postow');
```

By doing this, you will have a working structure for your shortcode. Now, your second mistake is that your function needs to return a value, thats what your shortcode will be transformed into. To do this, you need to use `return`.

**Edit:** Plus, your logic to retrive posts names was wrong, so I fixed it:

So, your fixed code will look like:

```
//[tutuly id="1"]
function tytuly_postow($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'id' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'category'       => $id,
          'post_status'    => 'publish'
   );
   $myposts = get_posts($args);
   if ($myposts) {
          $q = '<p>';
          foreach ($myposts as $post) {
                 $q .= apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title) . '<br />';
          }
          $q .= '</p>';
   } else {
          $q = '';
   }

   return $q;
}
add_shortcode('tytuly','tytuly_postow');
```

`posts_per_page` is now set to `-1` to retrieve all posts,
`post_status` is used to retrieve only posts that are published.

If you want to retrieve links for your posts, instead of just the name, you can change this line:

`$q .= apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title) . '<br />';`

to

`$q .= '<a href=' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '>' . apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title) . '</a><br />';`

Notice that if you don't have enough programming skills, you can always use the awesome [GenerateWP Shorcodes Generator](http://generatewp.com/shortcodes/).

Comment: In the example given returning $q isn't helpful. The query itself and the values assigned to the variable aren't going to work.

Comment: I just have fixed it.

Comment: Fair enough but now the question needs to be asked, was the answer necessary given it's a copy of the answer I posted. Also just to make you aware you have the post object so when using get_permalink you should pass the object and not the ID. It's more efficient.